# R - Sum within group and only if another variable has consecutive values

Tags: r, stata

I have a dataframe where each row is a firm on a specific month. I have two columns: amount of money and number of transactions. I need to identify those firms who have at least 150.0 in the amount of money column and at least 11 on the number of transactions column, by trimester. I have approximately 50 months of observations.

In Stata, what I did was to sort the data by id and month, then ask whether the sum of the trimester is higher that the conditions. This I did by using the [_n] functionality of Stata: having the data sorted and being in observation [_n], I know that observation [_n-1] is the same firm in the earlier month:

```
by id: replace auxactivado = 1 if auxactivado != 1 & !missing(amount) & ///
(amount[_n] + amount[_n-1]) > 150.00 & !missing(transac) & ///
(transac[_n] + transac[_n-1]) >= 10 & (mes[_n] == (mes[_n-1] + 1) | mes[_n] == 1 & mes[_n-1] == 12 & ao[_n] != ao[_n-1])
```

In the Stata code above I check whether the condition is met in just two months, for example (I also check for year changes; in the data below I created an auxiliar month which adjusts for this, so no need to make this adjustment anymore).

I would like to do this in R, but have no clue how. I have extensively looked online but could not come up with a solution. Any ideas would be much appreciated

```
month   year   monthaux           id    amount  transac
    2   2019         26      1201857     301.0     7
    3   2019         27      1201857     423.9     9
    4   2019         28      1201857     684.7    10
    5   2019         29      1201857     494.1     6
    4   2018         16      1202268     51       13
    5   2018         17      1202268     80       15
    2   2019         26      1202268     20       53
    6   2017          6      1202545     102.97    6
    7   2017          7      1202545     2429.6    1
    8   2017          8      1202545     1735.0    1
```

This is a piece of my data in case I was not clear. Note that the months are not always consecutive: I need to check the condition only on consecutive months.

I would like id 1201857 to show as 1 (meets conditions), 1202268 as 0 (meets transactions but not amount due to no-consecutive month) and 1202545 as 0 (meets amount, does not meet transac condition)

Edit: eastclintw00d has been helping me and there is some trouble with data of this sort, where the conditions are met within two months.

```
id  month   year    amount  transac
2068814 9   2016    151.18  5
2068814 10  2016    206.36  7

2037434 8   2018    85.43   1
2037434 10  2018    744.91  4
2037434 11  2018    630.8   6
2037434 1   2019    596.33  3
```

```
structure(list(id = c(2068814L, 2068814L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 
2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 
2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 
2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L, 2037434L), ao = c(2016L, 2016L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L, 
2019L, 2019L), mes = c(9L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), importe_dol = c(151.18, 
206.36, 268.85, 299.97, 63.99, 797.27, 525, 643.15, 108.58, 128.21, 
452.24, 403.25, 92, 1003.45, 158.96, 85.43, 744.91, 630.8, 596.33, 
574.02, 80.50351324, 444.9815415), cant_transac = c(5, 7, 2, 
1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 6, 3, 4, 1, 3)), row.names = c(45L, 
811L, 10507L, 12459L, 15487L, 16601L, 19590L, 22927L, 27284L, 
30505L, 33036L, 36794L, 41810L, 43778L, 49722L, 54720L, 61910L, 
67047L, 77803L, 89001L, 97082L, 100933L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: U mean, add a column in the dataframe showing if the ID meet the condition or not ? conditions is .. 1)Amount for each row must be at least 150 ... 2) Transaction Must be at least 11 ... 3) and monthes must be consecutive ?? or you mean the sum of amount and transaction must meet the minimum for IDs and must be consecutive monthes ?

Comment: For id `1202268`, there are rows for months `2`, `3`, and `4` of `2019`, which are in the same trimester and are consecutive. If we sum the `amount` for those rows, we get `1413.96`, which is greater than 150`, every `transaction` for these rows is over `11` so the sum is over 11. So why do you say 1202268 does not meet criteria *"not amount due to no-consecutive month"*?

Comment: I'm also confused by your "trimester" definition. In your Stata code, you seem to be checking the previous month always, whether it is consecutive or not, regardless of number. Normally a trimester is defined as months 1-4, 5-8, 9-12. Is this the meaning you want?

Comment: Sorry, Gregor, I deleted the data about 1202268 you mentioned because it was wrong, as you said. Omar, I meant the sum of amount and transactions, as you correctly guessed.

Comment: I meant trimester as three consecutive months, indeed, not trimester as Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. Sorry for not being thorough enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your table is called `df` try:

```
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
  group_by(id, year, trimester = ceiling(month / 4)) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(transac, amount), sum) %>% 
  mutate(criterion = if_else(transac >= 11 & amount >= 150, 1, 0))
```

---

Given your clarification regarding trimesters the following code should do the trick. I first create a cartesian product of the three key variables and then join your dataframe on it. I create 1st and 2nd lag of the relevant variables and check whether they meet the criteria. Finally, I filter for those entries that you are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(
  data.frame(ao = min(df$ao):max(df$ao)),
  data.frame(mes = 1:12),
  data.frame(id = unique(df$id))
) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% mutate(original = 1), by = c("ao", "mes", "id")) %>% 
  arrange(id, ao, mes) %>% 
  mutate(
    cant_transac2 = if_else(id == lag(id), lag(cant_transac), NA_real_), 
    cant_transac3 = if_else(id == lag(id, 2), lag(cant_transac, 2), NA_real_), 
    importe_dol2 = if_else(id == lag(id), lag(importe_dol), NA_real_), 
    importe_dol3 = if_else(id == lag(id, 2), lag(importe_dol, 2), NA_real_), 
  ) %>% 
  replace_na(list(cant_transac2 = 0, cant_transac3 = 0, importe_dol2 = 0, importe_dol3 = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(criterion = if_else(cant_transac + cant_transac2 + cant_transac3 >= 11 & importe_dol + importe_dol2 + importe_dol3 >= 150, 1, NA_real_)) %>% 
  filter(original == 1) %>% 
  select(-original, -cant_transac2, -cant_transac3, -importe_dol2, -importe_dol3)
```

Comment: This is my best guess as well, but I *think* OP would want to group by `year` also...

Comment: FYI, you can save a line and define `trimester` in the `group_by`. Don't need to `mutate` first.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try this as soon as I can (which unfortunately is not right now). If you allow me to abuse your generosity, how would I create a column in my data containing whether the criteria is met or not? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. I have tried the code but, as Gregor noted above, I am not referring to "trimesters" in the traditional sense. I define a trimester as three consecutive months, i.e. months nov-dec-jan would be a trimester. I am sorry I was not clear at all regarding this, but your code does not contemplate this and I am not sure how to fix it (actually achieving this was my main issue when I posted the question). Thank you.

Comment: I had posted a comment with a silly issue I have already resolved. Thank you very much, this seems to work, although I cannot yet check it fully. How should I modify the code as to have the same data I had before, but now adding "criterion" as a column? This way I can compare it with Stata code I have, and finally resolve all my problems. You have been very helpful and I am marking your answer as correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I truly did not expect you to help me this much. You have undoubtedly saved me a lot of hours. I have just checked the code against Stata, and it seems to have an issue with the firms that meet the condition in two months. In the next comment, I present data for two firms that should have been flagged as meeting the conditions but were not. I looked at the code but have not found a clear reason as to why is this specific slip happening

Comment: `id month year amount transac  

2068814 9 2016 151.18 5  
2068814 10 2016 206.36 7  
    
2037434 8 2018 85.43 1  
2037434 10 2018 744.91 4  
2037434 11 2018 630.8 6  
2037434 1 2019 596.33 3`
Sorry, I tried for hours to add line breaks but does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Could you please add an export of all relevant data using `dput` to your question? For example, use `dput(mtcars)` and copy the console output.

Comment: I have just edited the answer to include data regarding what I am talking about. Thank you. Note: the condition is for transac to be >= 10. The code you gave me has 11 instead of 10, I have already corrected this (that is why id 2037434 should be flagged as meeting the criteria: because of months 10/2018 and 11/2018

Comment: Please use `dput(df)` so I can get the data easily into my script.

Comment: The key was to replace `NA`s in the lagged variables. However, I can not find any timepoint when id `2037434` should be marked.

Comment: It should be marked because it has a >150 amount and >=10 transac during months 10 and 11 of 2018 (it complies with the conditions not in 1 nor in 3, but in 2 months, which is correct. I do not care if then the firm does not appear anymore or whatever). I am trying this revision right now. Thank you once again.

Comment: Oh, you stated in your question that IDs should only be selected it they have at least 11 transactions. Just change the value in the `criterion` calculation to be `10` rather than `11` and the code works fine.

Comment: Awesome! We have a difference in 7 out of about 6500 firms, and your code is right. Thank you so much. Really. This is great. I have also managed to write another piece of the code in R all by myself, so I could not be happier :)